# How to compare rows in two identical tables and return result set of missing rows?

Tags: sql, mysql

I've looked through all the related questions, but none of them does exactly what I need. I have two identically-structured tables (id, VoucherNbr, BalanceInit) - one is from our current production system (tableA), and the other is from a client's legacy system (tableB). Table A has records a,b,c,d,e (for example), and table B has a,b,c,d,e,f,g. Table B will always have all the values that exist in table A, but also has extra rows. I need to return a resultset that contains all the rows in table B that don't exist in table A (f and g, using the example.) How can I do this?

EDIT:

TABLE A

```
ID | VoucherNbr         | BalanceInit
=============================================
1  | 1111111111111111   | 25.00
2  | 2222222222222222   | 50.00
3  | 3333333333333333   | 10.00
```

TABLE B

```
ID | VoucherNbr         | BalanceInit
=============================================
15 | 1111111111111111   | 25.00
17 | 1212121212121212   | 15.00
22 | 2222222222222222   | 50.00
34 | 3333333333333333   | 25.00
41 | 3232323232323232   | 75.00
```

What I need to get back is a resultset containing only the rows that don't exist in Table A, where it's the value in the VoucherNbr field that doesn't exist, not the ID field.

```
ID | VoucherNbr         | BalanceInit
=============================================
17 | 1212121212121212   | 15.00
41 | 3232323232323232   | 75.00
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some databases offer this feature directly using a SUBTRACT or MINUS operation.  MySQL doesn't seem to have any such operation.

I would probably do this:

```
SELECT  B.id, B.voucherNbr, B.balanceInit FROM tableB B
   WHERE NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT * FROM tableA A 
      WHERE A.voucherNbr = B.voucherNbr AND A.balanceInit = B.balanceInit)
```

However, here are a couple of other MySQL solutions (I googled them) you can test for speed:

```
SELECT  id, voucherNbr, balanceInit FROM tableB 
   WHERE (voucherNbr, balanceInit) NOT IN 
      (SELECT voucherNbr, balanceInit FROM tableA);

SELECT  id, voucherNbr, balanceInit
   FROM tableB LEFT JOIN tableA USING (voucherNbr, balanceInit)
      WHERE tableA.voucherNbr IS NULL
```

Honestly, I like the first googled solution better than my own if the execution time is similar or better.

*Note: I've modified these from my original answer to reflect the fact that you state in a comment to another answer that the ids vary in the two tables.*

Answer (score 1):

Note: Assuming `id` is the PK for both tables.

```
SELECT B.* FROM TableB B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA A
ON B.id = A.id
WHERE A.id IS NULL
```

EDIT : Based on further commments from OP, since Id's are different for the same rows in the two tables, assuming that the matching criteria is based on comparing the 2 column values

```
SELECT B.* FROM TableB B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA A
ON B.VoucherNbr = A.VoucherNbr
AND B.BalanceInit = A.BalanceInit
WHERE A.VoucherNbr IS NULL
```

EDIT2 : If only voucher number itself is sufficient, then balanceInit too can be discarded

```
SELECT B.* FROM TableB B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA A
ON B.VoucherNbr = A.VoucherNbr
WHERE A.VoucherNbr IS NULL
```

Comment: Well, that's sort of the problem. It IS the PK for both tables, but the rows may not be in the same order in each table. For example, in table A, value b might be id=2, whereas in table B, value b might be id=50. I'm guessing your query won't work if that's the case?

Comment: Thanks! The edited version worked as well; I had already accepted another answer while you were posting, so sorry you're not getting points for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **INTERSECT** stament

```
SELECT * FROM tableA 
INTERSECT 
SELECT * FROM tableB
```

-EXCEPT returns any distinct values from the left query that are not also found on the right query.

**-INTERSECT returns any distinct values that are returned by both the query on the left and right sides of the INTERSECT operand.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

Comment: No, actually I can't. If you hadn't noticed, the question is tagged MySQL, which doesn't support intersect. That's an MS SQL function.